# memory management question -- releasing an object which has to be returned

Tags: iphone

I have an NSMutableArray called playlist. This is in a method called getAllPlaylists. The code is something like this:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)getAllPlaylists
{
    //playlist is an instance variable
     playlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //memory leak here
    ...
    //some code here which populates the playlist array
    [playlist addObject: object1];
    ...
     return playlist;
}
```

The array allocation step of playlist is causing a memory leak. In such a scenario where can i release this array? Or can i avoid allocation n initialization of playlist here by doing something else? Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 solutions:

**Use `autorelease`:**

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getAllPlaylists
{
    playlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ...
    return [playlist autorelease];
}
```

or instead of using `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` to create your NSMutableArray object, **use `[NSMutableArray array]`** which is equivalent to `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]`:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getAllPlaylists
{
    playlist = [NSMutableArray array];
    ...
    return playlist;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! But the last time i tried playlist = [NSMutableArray array]; the app crashed. Anyways, i will try it once again.

Comment: This will work as long as you don't ever try using `playlist` in any other methods in your class.  In this case, it wouldn't make sense to have an instance variable at all (depends on what you're trying to do).

Comment: If you use `playlist = [NSMutableArray array];` make sure you don't attempt to release it anywhere. That will likely result in a crash.

Comment: I used playlist = [NSMutableArray array];

However, I was returning the playlist array and storing it in another NSMutableArray. The reason, why it crashed the first time i set playlist to autorelease, was that i did not retain the NSMutableArray to which i received the playlist array. Once i retained it and later released it using dealloc, the code worked fine.

Thanks a lot for your help guys!!

Answer (score 1):

You should autorelease newly created objects that you want to return that are not owned by the object (local variables, not instance variables).

```
playlist = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Alternatively, you can use the convenience method to do that more easily:

```
playlist = [NSMutableArray array];
```

For items the object owns (instance variables), you should make sure you release the old value first and implement a `dealloc` method that also releases the value.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getAllPlaylists {
    [playlist release];
    playlist = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return playlist;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [playlist release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

For more info, see the [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

Comment: Thanks!! But, the first time when getAllPlaylists is called, the playlist array will not have any memory allocation to release. Wont that cause an error?

Comment: The first time `getAllPlaylists` is called, `playlist` will be `nil`.  Sending a message to `nil` [is allowed](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW7) in Objective-C.

Comment: Read that [memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) over and over.  Even if you don't understand it the first time, spend some time coding, then come back to it.  Eventually it will click.